# GIT - get changes from branch to master as changes

Tags: git

I have master and develop branch.

In develop branch I have commit1.

Question:

**How to add changes from commit1(develop) to master branch as local changes (uncomitted changes)?**

Comment: Why do you want those changes but not committed?  There are a couple of ways to accomplish what you want, most straight forward one may depend on why you want to do this.

Comment: Basicily I want to take out commit from branch and threat it like local changes, so I make some more changes and commit it to master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git merge` in `master` branch.

```
git merge develop
```

If you want to merge without `commit`, just add `--no-commit` and `--no-ff`.

```
git merge develop --no-commit --no-ff
```

Comment: I want to see changes as uncomited changes ( local changes )

Answer (score 0):

Most common workflow in git is to just continue working on a branch until you feature is finish or bug is fixed and then merge it back into its parent branch (in your case *master*).

However, if you do want to bring changes from one branch over into the other, you have a few options.

1. Use the [`git merge`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) command as Landys mentioned.  Either `--no-commit` or `--squash` will bring changes from another branch over without actually committing them.  You'll probably need to do a `git reset` to unstage the changes that you just merged in.  This will bring all the changes from all of the commits over.
2. Another option is described here: [Quick tip: git-checkout specific files from another branch](http://nicolasgallagher.com/git-checkout-specific-files-from-another-branch/).  Basically you can use [`git checkout`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to specify a specific file you want to check out from another branch or use patch mode (`-p`) to select which changes you want to check out from the other branch and which you don't.
3. If you have several commits on another branch and you want to bring only one of them over to your current branch, you could use [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) to bring that commit over and then [`git reset HEAD~`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to undo the commit `cherry-pick` made but not modify the files in your working directory.